# mp4parser - how to start using?

Tags: android, mp4parser, aspectj-maven-plugin

I want to merge multiple videos sequentially and get one video with [mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser)
but can't start using it...
I added in file gradle - `implementation 'org.mp4parser:isoparser:1.9.27'`
and following the example, it is impossible to find

> Movie()

then I realize that I need to add the plugin aspectj-rt.jar, but can't find up-to-date information on it

please help me with this problem.
I see in the network that various developers successfully use this library to work with video files. But nowhere is there information on how to get started with mp4parser.

Comment: what is problem there now

Comment: @sashabeliy there is no example on adding dependencies to work with mp4parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked for me

```
implementation "com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22"
```

Comment: I'm facing a lot of OutOfmemoryException when I use this version.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the latest version of mp4parser you have to add an additional library to it `implementation 'org.mp4parser:muxer:1.9.41'` to get all the missing classes Movie() and many other.

Please add the following:

```
implementation 'org.mp4parser:isoparser:1.9.41'  
implementation 'org.mp4parser:muxer:1.9.41'
```

Answer (score 1):

implementation 'org.mp4parser:isoparser:1.9.41 ' try following dependcy and let me know

Comment: to work with these lines:
List<Movie> inMovies = new ArrayList<Movie>()